# Stuck on doubling size of hashtable

Tags: java, hash, dictionary

I can't figure out how to double the size of my hash table. Here is the code:

```
private void doubleLength () {
  //Remember the old hash table array and allocate a new one 2 times as big

  HashMap<K,V> resizedMap = new HashMap<K,V>(map.length * 2);

/*Traverse the old hash table adding each value to the new hash table.
 Instead, add it to by applying
 hashing/compression again (compression will be DIFFERENT, because the
 length of the table is doubled, so we compute the same hash value but
 compute the remainder using the DIFFERENT TABLE LENGTH).*/
   for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (K key : map[i].entry) { //iterator does not work here
                    resizedMap.put(key, map[i].get(key)); //should go here
    }

}
```

The hash table is an array of LN objects where LN is defined by:

```
public static class LN<K1,V1> {
   public Map.Entry<K1,V1> entry;
   public LN<K1,V1>        next;

   public LN (Map.Entry<K1,V1> e, LN<K1,V1> n)
   {entry = e; next = n;}
}
```

I have an iterable within my class but it doesn't allow for map[i].entry.entries().

```
public Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries () {
return new Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
  public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
    return new MapEntryIterator();
  }
};
}
```

I'm very lost on how I can double the size of public LN[] map;

Comment: I'm puzzled. The latter two snippets suggest you're implementing your own hashtable, but the first snippet suggests you're using java.util.HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

The `HashMap` already resizes itself when the hash table gets too full. You do not have to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile. If you want to initialize a map to double the size it is easier to do this (assuming `map` is a `Map` also):

```
private void doubleLength () {
  //Remember the old hash table array and allocate a new one 2 times as big
  HashMap<K,V> resizedMap = new HashMap<K,V>(map.size()* 2);
  resizedMap.putAll(map);
}
```

Also you seem to accessing things strangely. If you needed to loop through a map it shoudl look like:

```
for (K key : map.keySet()){
  V value = map.get(key); //get the value from the map
  //do what you need to do
}
```

Now as already stated, you do not need to resize the HashMap. It already does that. From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.